# set state after submit form in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

how do you change the state back to blank when the form has been submitted?
I tried to empty it again when the form was submitted, but the state still has value
when it is finished, submit the state back to the initial state

```
state = {
    importExcel: '',
    active: true
  };

  handlerChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      importExcel: e.target.files[0],
      active: !this.state.active
    });
  };

  handlerOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('importExcel', this.state.importExcel);

    api.post('web/user/import', formData)
    .then(res => {
      const { message, success } = res.data;
      const alert = swal({
        title: success === false ? 'Gagal Upload' : 'Berhasil Upload',
        text: message,
        icon: success === false ? 'error' : 'success',
        // timer: 5000,
        button: true
      })

      if (success === false) {
        return alert
      } else {
        return alert
      }
    })

    this.setState({
      importExcel: '',
      active: true
    })
  }
```

Comment: Have you logged the state to check if it is actually being emptied?

Comment: Could you give more detail? if the function handlerOnSubmit  is called at the end, this state will be your expect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (success === false) {
    return alert
} else {
   return alert
}
```

You are returning function every time. So the code below this line doesn't execute.